# VBA on data source update I want to update a different sheets sort order

Tags: vba, sorting, runtime-error

I have this working thus far for the datasource sheet.  But on another sheet called WatchList I want to update the sort order for 1 of the columns which does a look up when the data source updates.  I tried several items and cant get it working.

As far as my range it starts at at the top of the sheet WatchList and goes to column L.  And the sort I want to do is on column H.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim Sheet As Worksheet, Pivot As PivotTable
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
        Pivot.RefreshTable
        Pivot.Update
      Next
    Next
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("WatchList")
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A2:L69")
  ws.Range(rng).Sort Key1:=Range("H2:H69"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

I am getting run-time error '1004';
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `ws.Range(rng)`? It would seem like `rng` is on a different worksheet than `ws`.

Comment: it can be written differently that is just what I found already as an example.  I want to sort all rows on worksheet WatchList based on column H once there is an update from a datasource off a different worksheet it will then trigger updates on WatchList sheet column H.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I would love to get this working